# DDD repository/facade implementation + bounded context relationship

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, orm, repository, ddd

Вопрос в следующем, как лучше реализовать механизм `Include`?

Предположим, у нас есть `Repository` и нам требуется загрузить сущность со связанными элементами, в сервисе мы можем использовать следующий код:

```
repo.Select<School>().Include(sc => sc.Students).Include(sc => sc.Teachers);
```

или даже переопределить операцию `select` и передавать коллекцию `Include Expression` в качестве параметра:

```
 repo.Select<School>(sc => sc.Students, sc => sc.Teachers);
```

Cо временем наша школа становится платной, и мы создаем другой Bounded Context, в котором реализована логика по оплате / начислениям.

Еще через время нам понадобилось подружить две модели и мы хотим в нашем классе `Student` добавить `NotMapped` поле, которое бы определяло,например, имеет ли студент доступ к библиотеке (логика определения находится в другой модели).

И нам, в момент получения данных, нужно сделать инъекцию для класса `Student`:

```
Student student = repo.Select<Student>(p => p.Id == id);
bool access = ChargeService.GetBalanceInfo(id);
student.Init(access);
return student;
```

Теперь о проблеме, когда ты используешь `Include` в коде самого сервиса,тебе придется переписать кучу кода, чтобы сделать такую инъекцию.

Решение проблемы напрашивается - сделать отдельный метод в репозитории:

```
IEnumerable<School> GetSchoolWithStudentsAndTeachers();
```

Тогда инъекцию нужно будет провести только в этом месте. Но если ты имеешь большую модель, то количество таких методов в репозитории будет огромным, а их названия будут сводить с ума.

Можете подсказать, как бы вы поступили/поступаете в данной ситуации?

Comment: Если Вы рассчитываете на большое количество потребителей, каждый из которых сможет использовать нужную ему модель в нескольких местах, стоит ввести дополнительный слой абстракции, на котором их потребности будут разрешаться. Назовем это DataView или DataQuery. При этом сервисы перестают использовать репозиторий напрямую. ChargeService, например, будет использовать ChargeServiceDataView, в котором будет всё, что ему нужно. Вообще, если Вы хотите красивый DDD, я бы посоветовал почитать про Command Query Responsibility Segregation и Event Sourcing. Эта идея растет как раз оттуда.

Comment: @Fynivx, да, без дополнительного слоя тут точно не обойтись. Просто проблема возникла именно в реализации, где это описать - это уже второстепенное). Про CQRS спасибо, раньше читал, нужно будет как следует изучить этот материал. 
  Тут еще задача состоит в том, что бы не загружать лишние данные и выиграть на этом время.  Ты пытаешься распределить логику по разным моделям, дабы уменьшить связанность. В итоге тебе все равно приходится их дружить между собой, но на другом уровне. И с другими затратами (т.к. будет несколько запросов к бд и передача данных между сервисами).

Comment: если говорить именно о реализации, года полтора назад я решал именно такую проблему. Пришлось идти на компромисс - привязать классы, которые отвечают за компоновку запроса к EF (репозиторий возвращает IQueryable, клиент использует EFовский Include). Главный аргумент был такой - если мы будем отказываться от EF, всё равно весь DAL придется переписывать. Что же касается оверхеда по операциям с БД - это решается кешированием на уровне запроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Вашем описании `Student` это класс предметной области, однако, он загружается непосредственно из базы с помощью Entity Framework. Entity Framework не может устанавливать значения свойств только для чтения, так что Вы должны сделать все свойства доступными для изменения.

Но в предметной области некоторые поля неизменяемые, например, *идентификатор сущности*, *дата и время создания сущности*, и другие. Некоторые поля должны изменяться согласованно, например, новое состояние сущности и дата/время её последнего изменения. Именно такое согласованное изменение и называется *инкапсуляцией*.

`Student`, у которого все поля открыты, можно назвать *анемичной моделью*, которую, например, [Фаулер считает анти-паттерном (Anemic Domain Model)](https://habrahabr.ru/post/224879/).

Было бы правильно спрятать состояние полностью внутрь, а снаружи оставить только методы, которые согласованно меняют состояние сущности. С чем же тогда будет работать Entity Framework? С Data Transfer Object'ом, который отражает состояние сущности:

```
[Table("Student")]
public class StudentDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int SchoolId { get; set; }

    public virtual SchoolDto School { get; set; }

    . . .
}

public class Student
{
    private readonly StudentDto dto;

    internal Student(StudentDto dto)
    {
        this.dto = dto;

        School = new School(dto.School);
    }

    public int Id => dto.Id;

    public School School { get; }
}
```

В данном случае мы видим, что при загрузке студента из базы надо *включить* навигационное поле `School`. Это делает реализация класса-репозитория:

```
public class EFStudentRepository: IStudentRepository
{
    private readonly DbContextScope dbContextScope;

    public EFStudentRepository(DbContextScope dbContextScope)
    {
        this.dbContextScope = dbContextScope;
    }

    public Student ReadById(int id)
    {
        var dto = dbContextScope.Context
                                .Students.
                                .Include(x => x.School)
                                .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if (dto == null)
            throw new EntityNotFound(typeof(Student), id);

        return Student.From(dto);
    }
}
```

А вот как указывать репозиторию, какие навигационные свойства включать, а какие нет? Ответ DDD: это вопрос из другого уровня приложения. В предметной области нет понятия включенных классов, это термин уровня доступа к данным, причём термин конкретной библиотеки Entity Framework.

В DDD есть понятие составных сущностей: *агрегатов*. Например, заказ и товарные позиции в этом заказе. В базе данных это две разных таблицы, а на уровне предметной области: класс `Order` со свойством коллекцией `Products`. И заказ, и товарная позиция суть сущности, но заказ это корневая сущность агрегата, а товарная позиция просто в него входит. Значит, при загрузке из базы надо загружать корень агрегата и все данные, которые должны быть в агрегате в рамках данного *Bounded Context*.

Но считается, что одни агрегаты не должны содержать другие агрегаты, на них можно ссылаться только по идентификатору. Поскольку `School` — это, вероятно, отдельный агрегат, у `Student` должно быть свойство `SchoolId` вместо `School`.

Такое ограничение позволяет упростить слой доступа к данным. С другой стороны, из-за этого приходится чаще посылать к базе отдельные запросы для загрузки связанных агрегатов. Это цена, которая в DDD платится за то, чтобы сделать код понятнее и чище.

Таким образом, ответ из DDD звучит так: опишите агрегаты предметной области, достаточные для реализации её сценариев. Загрузку независимых агрегатов опишите в репозиториях в явном виде. Например, сценарий требует получения всех учителей студента, а *учитель* и *студент* — независимые агрегаты. В этом случае в репозитории *учителей* надо реализовать метод загрузки всех учителей по идентификатору студента:

```
public interface ITeacherRepository
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<Teacher> ReadAllByStudentId(int studentId);
}
```

Сервисы загружают все необходимые данные и выполняют групповую операцию. На уровне сервисов также задаются транзакции, если это нужно.

Comment: Ваш ответ с пояснениями из книги, с небольшими примерами кода. Но, задача состоит в том, чтобы не загружать лишние данные и выиграть на этом время. Вы предлагаете писать методы в репозитории в явном виде. Как я понимаю, от `LazyLoading` нужно отказаться вовсе и вместо *синтаксического сахара* юзать методы репозитория. Что по своей сути немного противоречит здравому смыслу, так как репозиторий станет гигантски большим. То есть реализации механизма `Include` - это методы в репозитории. И такой ответ имеет место быть. Отдаю вознаграждение вашему ответу, чтобы оно не пропало зря.

Comment: Оптимизация требует предварительного мониторинга. Дональд Кнут утверждает, что premature optimization is the root of evil, и в этом утверждении есть большая доля истины. Конкретно, при загрузке данных по сети много времени расходуется на установку соединения. Передача данных в быстрой локальной сети может занимать совсем немного времени. Иначе говоря, при росте объёма передаваемых данных время передачи сначала фиксировано, и лишь при достижении некоторого предела, оно начинает расти линейно. В быстрых локальных сетях этот предел достигает несколько килобайт.

Answer (score 2):

Прошу прощения, если не в тему. Я из мира PHP и сталкивался с похожей проблемой, если я правильно ее понял.

Насколько я понял, проблема в том, как изменять запросы в результате естественного развития проекта так, чтобы ничего не потерять и репозитории не разрастались.

Один из способов решения этой задачи - это шаблон проектирования [Спецификация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) *(пример в вики возможно не самый удачный)*. Вот еще пример на [.NET](https://habrahabr.ru/post/171559/) и на [PHP](http://blog.byndyu.ru/2014/07/command-and-query-responsibility.html). А вот пример реализации библиотеки на [PHP](https://github.com/Happyr/Doctrine-Specification) *(под C# тоже должно быть что-то такое)*. Возможно поможет понять общую идею.

Вкратце. Мы создаем простые классы спецификаций и компонуя их получаем требуемый результат. Очень грубо по вашему промеру:

```
repo.match(new AndSpec(
    new SchoolSpec(),
    new JoinStudents(),
    new JoinTeachers()
))
```

три разных спецификации группируются в одну. Можно вызывать такую группировку из контроллера или из Query в контексте CQRS как предложил @Fynivx.
Можно 3 спецификации объединить в одну большую `SchoolWithStudentsAndTeachersSpec`.

Надеюсь это то что вас интересует.

PS: Говоря о **Bounded Context** и DDD, я все больше прихожу к мысли, что в каждом контексте должны быть свои сущности и они ни как не должны взаимодействовать с сущностями в других контекстах. Статья на хабре о [микросервисах](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/320962/) натолкнула меня на мысль что **Bounded Context** нужно рассматривать как потенциальный микросервис. И соответственно связи между контекстами должны быть минимизированы. А если нам нужно в одном контексте использовать сущности из другого контекста, то мы должны использовать адапторы или маппить БД на свои собственные сущности которые отвечают требованиям нашего контекста. Суперглобальные агрегаты это плохо. Вопросы практического использования DDD хорошо описаны в книге [Вон Вернона](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/35045716/).